# Android: how to save the first preview frame from SurfaceView

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I was wondering if it is possible to save the `first frame` from camera preview, visible on a `SurfaceView`.
Within my activity I've currently implemented all the `SurfaceHolder.Callback` methods. When I call `startPreview` on camera object and than `takePicture` the callback is executed correctly, but I need to take and save the picture more quickly, so take the first visible frame of the preview would be very useful. 
What can I do?
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It might seem incredibly simple, but I would do something like this to save the first frame into a `Bitmap`.

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

                    if (image == null) {
                        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        yuvImage = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, camera
                                .getParameters().getPreviewSize().width, camera
                                .getParameters().getPreviewSize().height, null);

                        yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, camera
                                .getParameters().getPreviewSize().width, camera
                                .getParameters().getPreviewSize().height), 0,
                                out);

                        imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
                        image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0,
                                imageBytes.length);
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: I've tried your code, it works, but image has really low resolution. I've tried to change ImageFormat to JPEG, but it's not supported. What can I do?

Comment: Have you set the `PreviewSize` to a decent value in your `SurfaceChanged`? If not, set it to the width and height of surfaceholder. I can provide you some example code if you want, I'm actually working on something using a `SurfaceView` at the moment.

Comment: I've tried to set those parameters, but the image doesn't change and it's pixelated.